# Remove constant columns from an RDD and compute the covariance matrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark, covariance, rdd

My RDD might have columns with constant value. In other words, the variance of some of the columns may be zero. My objective is to remove all such columns from the RDD (and ultimately compute the covariance matrix for the remaining columns). How can I do that?

Thanks and regards,

Answer (score 6):

An RDD is supposed to be immutable. So I don't think you want to *remove* something from it, but just `map` it to something that suits you and/or `filter` something out (more details in the [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.0/api/core/#spark.RDD)).

Comment: Suppose I need to remove the first two columns from the RDD. How do I do it?

Comment: I guess you need to `map` it using a function that cuts off the first two columns from each record.